# Django download file in new tab which renders also a template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have a template which contains a button which, when clicked, submits some information via a GET request. This information is sent to a function in the `views.py` file.

On the template where the button is placed I have specified that the form submits in a new blank tab/window (`" < form target="_blank" ... >"`).

The function in the `views.py` file generates a CSV file via an `Httpresponse`:

```
response = HttpResponse("CSV_file_content", mimetype="text/csv")
response["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=%s.csv" % (filename)
return response
```

But I would also like to render an HTML template alongside to the download, something close to what is done with the `render_to_response('template.html')` function.

Do you have any idea how to implement this?

Comment: Do you want to open two URLs at once? You can do it using Javascript.

Comment: How could I open this new url with javascript?